# Loading a custom ApplicationContextInitializer in AWS Lambda Spring boot

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

How to loada custom  ApplicationContextInitializer to in spring boot AWS Lambda?
I have an aws lambda application using spring boot, I would like to write an ApplicationContextInitializer for decrypting database passwords. I have the following code that works while running it as a spring boot application locally, but when I deploy it to the AWS console as a lambda it doesn't work.

Here is my code
1. applications.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=testuser
CIPHER.spring.datasource.password=encryptedpassword
```

The following code is the ApplicationContextInitializer, assuming password is Base64 encoded for testing only (In the actual case it will be encrypted by AWM KMS). The idea here is if the key is starting with 'CIPHER.' (as in  CIPHER.spring.datasource.password)I assume it's value needs to be decrypted and another key value pair with actual, key (here spring.datasource.password) and its decrypted value  will be added at context initialization.

will be like `spring.datasource.password=decrypted password`

```
@Component
public class DecryptedPropertyContextInitializer 
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  private static final String CIPHER = "CIPHER.";

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
      for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : environment.getPropertySources()) {
          Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides = new LinkedHashMap<>();
          decodePasswords(propertySource, propertyOverrides);
          if (!propertyOverrides.isEmpty()) {
              PropertySource<?> decodedProperties = new MapPropertySource("decoded "+ propertySource.getName(), propertyOverrides);
              environment.getPropertySources().addBefore(propertySource.getName(), decodedProperties);
          }
      }
  }

  private void decodePasswords(PropertySource<?> source, Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides) {
    if (source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
        EnumerablePropertySource<?> enumerablePropertySource = (EnumerablePropertySource<?>) source;
        for (String key : enumerablePropertySource.getPropertyNames()) {
            Object rawValue = source.getProperty(key);
            if (rawValue instanceof String && key.startsWith(CIPHER)) {
                String cipherRemovedKey =  key.substring(CIPHER.length());
                String decodedValue = decode((String) rawValue);
                propertyOverrides.put(cipherRemovedKey, decodedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

  public String decode(String encodedString) {
    byte[] valueDecoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encodedString);
    return new String(valueDecoded);
  }
```

Here is the Spring boot initializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.amazonaws.serverless.sample.springboot.controller")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver() {
        return new HandlerExceptionResolver() {
            @Override
            public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

   //loading the initializer here
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication application=new SpringApplication(Application.class);
     application.addInitializers(new DecryptedPropertyContextInitializer());
     application.run(args);
    }
```

This is working when run as a spring boot appliaction, But when it deployed as a lambda into AWS the main() method in my SpringBootServletInitializer will never be called by lambda. Here is my Lambda handler.

```
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamLambdaHandler.class); 

    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
            handler.onStartup(servletContext -> {
                FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("CognitoIdentityFilter", CognitoIdentityFilter.class);
                registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
            });
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

What change is to be made in the code to load the ApplicationContextInitializer by Lambda? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to nail it in the following way.

First changed the property value with place holder with a prefix, where the prefix denotes the values need to be decrypted, ex.

spring.datasource.password=${MY_PREFIX_placeHolder}

aws lambda environment variable name should match to the placeholder

('MY_PREFIX_placeHolder') and it value is encrypted using AWS KMS (This sample is base64 decoding).

create an ApplicationContextInitializer which will decrypt the property value

```
public class DecryptedPropertyContextInitializer 
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  private static final String CIPHER = "MY_PREFIX_";

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
      for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : environment.getPropertySources()) {
          Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides = new LinkedHashMap<>();
          decodePasswords(propertySource, propertyOverrides);
          if (!propertyOverrides.isEmpty()) {
              PropertySource<?> decodedProperties = new MapPropertySource("decoded "+ propertySource.getName(), propertyOverrides);
              environment.getPropertySources().addBefore(propertySource.getName(), decodedProperties);
          }
      }
  }

  private void decodePasswords(PropertySource<?> source, Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides) {
    if (source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
        EnumerablePropertySource<?> enumerablePropertySource = (EnumerablePropertySource<?>) source;
        for (String key : enumerablePropertySource.getPropertyNames()) {
            Object rawValue = source.getProperty(key);
            if (rawValue instanceof String && key.startsWith(CIPHER)) {
                String decodedValue = decode((String) rawValue);
                propertyOverrides.put(key, decodedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

  public String decode(String encodedString) {
    byte[] valueDecoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encodedString);
    return new String(valueDecoded);
  }
}
```

The above code will decrypt all the values with prefix MY_PREFIX_ and add them at the top of the property source.

As the spring boot is deployed into aws lambda, lambda will not invoke the main() function, so if the ApplicationContextInitializer is initialized in main() it is not going to work. In order to make it work need to override createSpringApplicationBuilder() method of SpringBootServletInitializer, so SpringBootServletInitializer will be like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.amazonaws.serverless.sample.springboot.controller")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver() {
        return new HandlerExceptionResolver() {
            @Override
            public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }


@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder createSpringApplicationBuilder() {
  SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder();
  builder.initializers(new DecryptedPropertyContextInitializer());
  return builder;
}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

No need to make any changes for the lambdahandler.